# Angular JS meta tags

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone help on Angular JS Meta tags.

I have configured ngmeta properly but when am sharing the link on Whatsapp or facebook am, getting as below.

```
{{ngmeta.title}}
{{ngmeta.description}}
http://www.example.com
```